# How to install Gimp 2.8.2 on unity ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

Merry Christmas everyone! My first post as a new Linux user.

The gimp version in ubuntu software center is 2.6, will it automatically updated to 2.8.2 after installation?

How to install all the plugins as we can do in Linux Mint?

Thank you in advance!

"Never be afraid to ask the same questions as the answers can always be different!"

Answer (score 5):

You should add the following PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
```

and install

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

You will get GIMP `2.8.2` :) Enjoy!

[image]